# newbie : porting android to our own platform

Tags: android, porting

I would like to port android to our own industrial pc.

which skill set will I need from android software point of view for successfully porting it ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your industrial PC an X86 machine? If yes, then Android is available off the shelf

http://code.google.com/p/live-android/

Only generic admin skills would be required in terms of configuring drivers for touch panels and other components used in the PC (E.g. Data capture cards).

EDIT : Looks like that project is not maintained. Alternative is : http://www.android-x86.org/

Comment: thanks for the answer...how autoupdate work in such forks ? and did you mean x86 ?

Comment: Yes, its X86. Regarding auto update, you will have to maintain it yourself since updates are provided by specific vendors E.g. Samsung/LG.  Woukld be best to factor in 1 man month effort each year to jump to then current version of android.

Comment: If you select devices that are already supported by Linux, no efforts would be required on driver development. However, efforts would be required to prepare a configuration that works well with Linux kernel on Android.